# Can't Make Expanded Text Work Inside a Row Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a List (its not listview) that is being rendered inside a SingleChildScrollView. Each item of this list is like Card, that its divided this order: Padding > Container > Row > Container | Column > Text | Row > Expanded > Text

Inside this last Text Widget, I need to expand it because i'm using TextOverFlow.ellipsis effect...

Heres the widget code:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
       children: [
    Container(...),
Column(
    children: List.generate(data.length, (index) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      constraints: const BoxConstraints(
        minHeight: 120,
      ),
      child: Row(children: [
        Container(
          color: _switchColor(data[index].type),
          width: 15,
          height: 120,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 50.0, right: 14),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment:
                CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                data[index].title,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                      data[index].description,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black),
                      maxLines: 3,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
      ]),
    ),
  );
}));
);
```

I have already tried wrapping all the columns and rows inside Expanded,tried MainAxisSize.min...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are using `Expanded` over Text to get available space, its parent also need to get available space for the child. Size goes up.

Wrap top level `Padding` with Expanded widget.

```dart
Expanded(//this
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0, right: 14),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text(
          data[index].title,
          style: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            fontSize: 16,
          ),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
```

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints)